# Multiple User Authentication System in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I have 3 types of users in my projects.

```
1. Admin (admin.domain.com)
2. Brands (brand.domain.com)
3. Users (domain.com)
```

Based on the DB design decision we will have 3 separate tables `admins`, `users` and `brands`. I need to create 3 authentication user types. The Laravel documentation was not helpful in understanding on how this can be achieved.

Coming from rails, we had a very easy way of using namespaces with the devise gem to achieve this. Is there any plugin to achieve this or any guide which I can follow to implement the same.

I am using Laravel 6.

Comment: Generally you don't use multiple tables for this; you have a single `users` table and a separate `roles` (or `groups`) table to differentiate them. Also, asking for a plugin or tutorial/guide is considered off-topic for Stackoverflow...

Comment: @TimLewis Thanks. Do you suggest a single table?

Comment: I would, yes, but there's arguments for both approaches. If you need additional information that an `admin` has that a `user` wouldn't, you can use `nullable` columns, or pivot columns, or a separate table for `admin_information`, etc. etc., but I personally haven't seen a use case that requires 3 separate tables and the headache that comes with tying that to Laravel's auth logic.

Comment: Yes in Laravel it looks very painful. Didn't really have a problem doing that in Rails. My only concern is that If people are logging in from the various subdomains. If they are a user they will gain access to that place even though they are not allowed since they will be logged in.

Comment: Thankfully, there's routing available for that, and in conjunction with Middleware for checking auth/roles, you can prevent that from happening: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing. Example: `Route::domain("admin.domain.com")->group(function(){ Route::group(["middleware" => "auth.admin"], function(){ ... } });` (Something like that), and `auth.admin` would contain the logic to prevent non-admins from accessing.

Comment: @TimLewis Thank you for the heads up. I will check that out. Any pointers on using a single table and using roles to have different types. would love to read more on how efficiently it can be done.

Comment: No problem! There's a few external auth systems for Laravel that use this approach (Sentry/Sentinel https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentinel/3.x, Spatie Persmissions https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission, etc.) so you can check them out to get a better idea of their approach.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200732/discussion-between-harsha-m-v-and-tim-lewis).